# Remove the signature element in SOAP

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, header

I'm consuming java based service in my WCF client(C#)application.

using java client I'm able to call the service success fully.
Buy I'm getting error while creating the equalant dot net based client.find my C# steps below.

**step1 :** added Service reference of the java service to my C# client.
  **Step2 :** converted the.jks file to PFX file and insialled the certificate in to my local machine. attached the required certificate to the service via config file.

**my web.Config file :**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
      <binding name="wsHttpSoap11" >
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
        <security 
        includeTimestamp="false"
        securityHeaderLayout="Lax"
        authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
        defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128Rsa15"
        enableUnsecuredResponse="false"
        messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
          messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10">
        <secureConversationBootstrap />
      </security>
      <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
  </bindings>    
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TehRightBehaviour">
      <clientCredentials>
        <!-- clientCertificate not defaultCertificate -->
        <clientCertificate findValue="xxxxxx" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="Root" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />  
<serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
          <defaultCertificate findValue="xxxxxx" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="Root" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
        </serviceCertificate>    
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
    <client>
     <endpoint name="WsSoap11"   address="https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9900/getCountryList/"   binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpSoap11"
    contract="GetCountryList.ICountryWSEndPoint" behaviorConfiguration="TehRightBehaviour" />
    </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

**expected SOAP at server side:**

```
     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:book="http://ws.endpoints.ugc.test1.com/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <soapenv:Header>
            <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
              <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EncKeyId-1BB74F4E06425F7BAA14187353371124">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"/>
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                  <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <ds:X509Data>
                      <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                        <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx</ds:X509IssuerName>
                        <ds:X509SerialNumber>1418734574</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                      </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                  </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
                <xenc:CipherData>                      <xenc:CipherValue>R/KqZUW1uAQYfdddFql7zFBIPBkRX/lrFgYmIygVf+dpGzmH9NQV6xGEj+csdmK1qI1v62UUx3l89NIwmbd9jnFzstwbPmHreqmKC5mm540xjDT3rFSMMA4jkhKaRhhyvkJv90LCxRN0I6F2sOgcXfuczJrKu/+tseugjzOxbBFXfI=</xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:ReferenceList>
                  <xenc:DataReference URI="#EncDataId-2"/>
                </xenc:ReferenceList>
              </xenc:EncryptedKey>
            </wsse:Security>
          </soapenv:Header>
          <soapenv:Body>
            <xenc:EncryptedData Id="EncDataId-2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content">
              <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
              <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                  <wsse:Reference URI="#EncKeyId-1BB74F4E025F7BAA14187353371124"/>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
              </ds:KeyInfo>
              <xenc:CipherData>
                <xenc:CipherValue>
                  cSPbiKSC57Ba6Fo1SQHdw2tfQ4vfJcawXujuj9u1jpYpbh8mSdSvXk8C5LTykNMZ/UzmX+Kofs6n          
                </xenc:CipherValue>
              </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedData>
          </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
```

**my WCF client generated SOAP** (Signature tag encrypted and added additionaly in wcf request)

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo1fsj9+ISdZEvpYPea9ZTPkAAAAAE8fIajroBEuUOgMQSniXqgkZzIA56qAZtFJnBidUH4P3di6gACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <o:BinarySecurityToken>
        <!-- Removed-->
      </o:BinarySecurityToken>
      <e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
          <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"></DigestMethod>
        </e:EncryptionMethod>
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <X509Data>
              <X509IssuerSerial>                   
                <X509IssuerName>CN=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx</X509IssuerName>
                <X509SerialNumber>1418734574</X509SerialNumber>
              </X509IssuerSerial>
            </X509Data>
          </o:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
        <e:CipherData>  
          <e:CipherValue> dI7F6+ADHtA/nZ122+kOEb6vXBWG+pOujI/v4kQePFAdivYAUAVNTmD3j5XWhBQTcFr9O2ChhLT8vJQSRTqrvxci51JF/cCcjWh/4UD1lYNrelGoYJdSPbtIkxYWbaAajscYyzU9xdDkh8fq0YEcbyYW6ycBm8idxW6koY=</e:CipherValue>
        </e:CipherData>
        <e:ReferenceList>
          <e:DataReference URI="#_2"></e:DataReference>
          <e:DataReference URI="#_3"></e:DataReference>
        </e:ReferenceList>
      </e:EncryptedKey>
      <e:EncryptedData Id="_3" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"></e:EncryptionMethod>
        <e:CipherData>
          <e:CipherValue>44wzjJ99VveK/hQp3X+8awc7XHDXxf/oHDAn62gitkG6j6YETL9E2iVkLrtcmA+3YKdDRmxCUpWpoWTTZ8/5Ac9inIlw+xzTWUW6Ef2lLItWiV/ZY31wBeh32DO3hGLX+GZBAU4u6r2jMgNvoudIeyNFO5BbWSNFlr1+iDC4N8qgJfQ+/2R8YZZnSzyuDGHsmoZzdEB/WjYkjlrd5cYp8hMovtExe7mMXTWPfzJSAJomV7nsyYy3NSpvfEeM0iJCwvBtUeFgBSrvsAzbRIw21tHj19XbvPYuts3apPsSgf0Cvb+6Bu80l1J4TVbOH9GBymfow+T+ZbuHuxKmkYwfddmsAVUWunOJ/I//QveHx5ps6jjg=</e:CipherValue>
        </e:CipherData>
      </e:EncryptedData>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body u:Id="_1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <e:EncryptedData Id="_2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"></e:EncryptionMethod>
      <e:CipherData>
        <e:CipherValue>
          m+Ze2d4gGQ3FS1z92yrKcEPh4/JqQ3wJHMGHbewuHmaZT2FbjBi2jsdID0usKlHR1Fu4ZpC3XdGjfpS4WPZmbVsftdgeh9JhSHQPRacAVeapccjhN5HDFQR3f6FnBxrMUwGU/YwxseLvjNWbccX0LUQTZhuVYzufG14U1PTWmIqaeL6bB9kONDYuDSObYBkijSgAVfsvX2+qNlc1VeKHNDIzOx==
        </e:CipherValue>
      </e:CipherData>
    </e:EncryptedData>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

kindly guide me to solve this issue

EDIT :

Error:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"></s:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns="">soap:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring xmlns="">General security error (WSSecurityEngine: No crypto property file supplied to verify signature)</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: "...but I'm getting error while creating the equivalent dot net based client" - Even though Stack Overflow is powerful, as yet we have not developed the collective ability known to your species as Mind Reading, so you will have to tell us WHAT THE ERROR IS.